# Count how many orderS daily have free shipping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I really need help in finding how many orders in each day of December 2018 that have this free shipping incentive.

Where in the month of December 2018, we provide customers a marketing incentive. After customers purchase their orders, they get to enjoy free shipping if they purchase another order within the next hour (60 minutes).

For example, if a customer purchases an order at 1.35pm, they will get free shipping if they purchase a second order between 1.35pm and 2.35pm on the same day. From 2.36pm onwards, there will be no free shipping.

Sample Data

| Datetime | CustomerID | Order ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 03:15 | aa771sb | 231932 |
| 2020-12-01 03:37 | aa771sb | 231245 |
| 2020-12-01 08:12 | ab236de | 231163 |
| 2020-12-02 13:26 | ae312qr | 231562 |
| 2020-12-02 04:52 | ae542we | 231984 |

I need to form a table like this.

| Day of Purchase | All Orders | No.Of Orders with free shipping incentive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-01 | xx | xx |
| 2018-12-02 | xx | xx |
| 2018-12-03 | xx | xx |
| 2018-12-31 | xx | xx |

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using? SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data *as a text table* in the question.  Why is there a business rule for "free shipping"?  Shouldn't the actual shipping costs be stored somewhere?

Comment: apologies, didn't notice it right away, i'm using sql server for this.

Comment: are you keeping shipping details,costs for orders in somewhere ? if no, so are you keeping day of purchase with time details ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! i just added sample data on another table. We just basically wanted to track how many orders we got in a day and those qualified with the free shipping incentive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know if the first order for the customer is within 1 hour of an order and then summarize by day.  This suggests window functions:

```
select convert(date, datetime),
       count(*) as num_orders
from (select t.*,
             min(datetime) over (partition by customerid) as min_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where datetime >= '2018-12-01' and
      datetime < '2019-01-01' and
      datetime < dateadd(hour, 1, min_datetime) and
      datetime > min_datetime
group by convert(date, datetime)
order by convert(date, datetime);
```

Note:  This assumes that two orders don't have exactly the same date/time value.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this with a combination of `LAG` and grouping**

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(Datetime AS date) [Day of Purchase],
    COUNT(*) [All Orders],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(second, PrevOrder, Datetime) <= 3600 THEN 1 END) [No.Of Orders with free shipping incentive]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      LAG(Datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Datetime) PrevOrder
    FROM table
) t
GROUP BY CAST(Datetime AS date)
```

Note that this still counts an order as free shipping if the other order was less than an hour ago, but on the previous day. For example 23:45 and 00:20.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps! Will try this one and let you know if it works.